# Arch Linux: Gnome Classic Terminal doesn't work

Tags: arch-linux, gnome-terminal, gnome-classic

Good day,

I installed Arch Linux with Gnome Classic as desktop environment. The problem now is that the Terminal doesn't work. When I click on the Terminal the mouse cursor indicates busy and then nothing happens. Can anybody tell me how I can stop the X-Server with a keyboard shortcut or how I can fix this? Arch Linux is pretty useless without a Terminal.

Comment: alt-ctr-backslash - instant exit from xorg

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue. Due to missing 'DISPLAY' variable in D-Bus session services system cannot start gnome-terminal and default file  manager nautilus. You need to properly configure **~/.initrc** and **~/.bashrc**. You can take the following steps

1. First configure your **~/.initrc file**. Arch provides a default configuration in '**/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d**' file. Copy the content of this file to **~/.initrc** to get the primary configuration.
2. Append the following line at the bottom of **~/.bashrc**

   *`dbus-update-activation-environment --all`*
3. Do a reboot

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for me: If you don't have a working terminal, enter a virtual console (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>), type

```
sudo locale-gen
```

and reboot.